# Is there a way (and if so how) to add a conditional trait into PCGen?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, racial-traits, pcgen

Pathfinder

Specifically what I am trying to do is add a racial trait to the Kitsune race that will replace two of the normal racial traits. I have successfully added a trait called "Naturally Skilled" into the program and it shows up/ works just fine however I need to cut out two of the other traits you would get naturally if you choose this trait.

Starting racial traits for a Kitsune:
Agile, Change Shape, Kitsune Magic, Low-Light Vision

What it should look like if I choose Naturally Skilled is:
Change Shape, Low-Light Vision, Naturally Skilled

So essentially I'm replacing both Agile and Kitsune Magic for Naturally Skilled. Is there a good way to code that in? I've been trying to find where in the code to put arguments like that but its like sifting through a barn full of hay for a hay colored needle.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm having the same problem with a different race. The alternate racial traits should remove multiple standard racial traits in many cases, but do not.